# Shoes Rb Hostname not known: sub.localhost:3000

Tags: ruby, shoes, ruby-2.2, shoes-4

I am using the shoes's GUI builder and I get the below error when I make a simple HTTP request to my local Rails server

So when I make the request

```
res = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse("http://sub.localhost:3000"))
```

I get the error:

```
Hostname not known: sub.localhost
/Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv-replace.rb:12:in `rescue in getaddress'
/Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv-replace.rb:9:in `getaddress'
/Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv-replace.rb:23:in `initialize'
/Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `open'
/Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `block in connect'
/Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:73:in `timeout'
/Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:878:in `connect'
/Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
/Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
/Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1375:in `request'
shoes.rb:24:in `request'
shoes.rb:63:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
-e:1:in `call'
/Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv-replace.rb:12:in `rescue in getaddress'
/Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv-replace.rb:9:in `getaddress'
/Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv-replace.rb:23:in `initialize'
/Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `open'
/Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `block in connect'
/Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:73:in `timeout'
/Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:878:in `connect'
/Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
/Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
/Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1375:in `request'
shoes.rb:24:in `request'
shoes.rb:63:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
-e:1:in `call'
```

My hosts file has `127.0.0.1 sub.localhost` and I can reach the address and make requests against it no problem, just not in the shoes project.

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31842209/how-can-i-make-simple-http-requests-within-a-ruby-shoes-gui-application) question's advice and bound my local ip address `ex 123.12.12.1`, but get the same error `Hostname not known: sub.123.12.12.1`

[This](http://shoes.code.whytheluckystiff.narkive.com/ZiHkOJH6/hostname-not-known) said to remove the line `resolv-replace.rb:9:in` in the shoes project, but I get the same error `Hostname not known: sub.123.12.12.1`

I'm on a Mac

Comment: I've seen this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [custom DNS resolver](http://www.mccartie.com/2016/03/14/modify-your-ruby-app%27s-dns-lookup.html) to ensure that Ruby looks at the `hosts` file:

```
require 'resolv-replace'

hosts_resolver = Resolv::Hosts.new('custom_hosts')
dns_resolver = Resolv::DNS.new

Resolv::DefaultResolver.replace_resolvers([hosts_resolver, dns_resolver])

require "net/http"
require "uri"

res = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse("http://sub.localhost:3000"))
```

Now `Net::HTTP` will use your custom resolver that checks `hosts` first and successfully resolve your custom domains.

Comment: This is perfect. I wish you got here sooner though, I ended up paying for `ngrok` to get it to work. ha.